# Matching expressions for Twilio TaskRouter workers on data in objects in arrays

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-taskrouter

I've got Twilio Taskrouter workers with attributes that look like as follows:

```
{
  "name": "Bob",
  "id": "45",
  "roles": [
    { "id": "19", "name": "Foobar" },
    { "id": "20", "name": "Foobaz" }
  ]
}
```

I'd like to write a queue expression to only match Workers with roles with an `id` of `20`. How would I do that?

It would look something like...

`"20" in roles.id`

...but this doesn't work. As it seems Taskrouter is not smart enough to "unroll" the ids and match within them (like using a tool like `jq`). I am not able to find a solution in the [Twilio Taskrouter expression docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/expression-syntax).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I can't find a solution for you with the data like that. A workaround I just considered would be to add an array of, for example, `role_ids` to your worker as well. You can keep the existing array of `roles`, but add a simpler data type to use in the expression matching.

So, the attributes would look like this:

```
{
  "name": "Bob",
  "id": "45",
  "roles": [
    { "id": "19", "name": "Foobar" },
    { "id": "20", "name": "Foobaz" }
  ],
  "role_ids": ["19", "20"]
}
```

And you could then use the expression:

```
"20" in role_ids
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is the solution which I ended up using. But it certainly would be nice to be able to query the nested structures!